# ResolveClientUrl in a virtual directory not pointing to domain root

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

I have a website with the following virtual directories, each one is configured as application root:

1. _root/website1
2. _root/website2
3. _root/website3

And each one of them have its own pointing domain:

1. [www.website1.com](http://www.website1.com)
2. [www.website2.com](http://www.website2.com)
3. [www.website3.com](http://www.website3.com)

When I call **ResolveClientUrl("~/Default.aspx")** being at website1, it returns:

> /website1/Default.aspx

which is correct, but the browser will then point the user to:

> http://www.website1.com/website1/Default.aspx

which is wrong, it should point to:

> http://www.website1.com/Default.aspx

I understand why is this happening, I wish to know if there is some work around to tell my application to ignore the virtual directory and assume it is in the root of the website, in this case the root of the domain? Perhaps overriding ResolveClientUrl and add a flag?

Comment: In IIS, AFAIK, you can only apply domain binding to a website, not a virtual directory. How did you associate the v. directories to different domains?

Comment: Also you should really change your tags to include iis for whatever version you are running this on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as code below:

string.Format(Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https://{0}{1}" : "http://{0}{1}", Request.Url.Host, Page.ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx"));